# Index by word length

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, new-operator

My aim was to simply make a hangman game. However, I have been slightly over-ambitious. I want to ask the user to input how long they want the word. Then choose a random word of that length. To index an entire dictionary of that length would take far too long on each iteration. So. I have a dictionary, formatted like so:

zymosans

zymoscope

zymoses

...

I would like to be able output a file for each 'length of word' automatically using this program. Like this:

1letterwords.txt

2letterwords.txt

and so forth.

I started python...yesterday. I searched both the web and this site and came up with nothing. 
I would like some pointers as to how to start with this specific programming problem.
Thanks in advance!
(To clarify, the hangman game would open a random line in the requested wordlength file, reducing performance impact...fairly dramatically.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post some code to demonstrate what you've tried so far.  It will make it much easier for us to make suggestions.

Comment: That's part of the problem haha, as a beginner I guess I dont even have the background to flail. All my code does is open the file...It's a sad state of affairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting random lines of files is probably not what you want to do either ... keeping them in a list and/or dict should be fine even for millions of words.

you can store list of words by their length by iterating over all your words and adding them to a list seeded defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

wordsByLength = defaultdict( list )
for word in allWords:
    wordsByLength[ len(word) ].append( word )
```

Then whenever you need a random word you can do:

```
randomLen = random.choice( wordsByLength.keys() )
randomWord = random.choice( wordsByLength[ randomLen ] )
```

Or you can replace randomLen with the specified length you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It's really not that big of a deal to load an entire dictionary into memory. You can try something like this:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

# load words
index = defaultdict(list)
with open('words.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        index[len(word)].append(word)

# pick a random word
length = int(raw_input('Enter word length: '))
word = random.choice(index[length])
```

And if you insist on generating separate files by word length, run this code after loading the index as shown above:

```
for length in sorted(index):
    path = 'words%d.txt' % length
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        for word in index[length]:
            file.write('%s\n' % word)
```

Comment: If I wanted it to be slightly more interactive would I be able to say use file=raw_input(Directory) then use your 'with open(file) as file'? Would that still work?

Comment: Second question:How do I run your code? I get the error " index[len(word)].append(word)"

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo that someone else has since corrected... see edited code.

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

```
url = urllib.urlopen('http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt')
random.choice([item for item in url if len(item) == 8])
```

Comment: Why would you hit a URL every time you want a random word?

Comment: I was more hoping he would have his own dictionary of words, the second line is the more important one

Comment: Yup, I have a dictionary of words. It's just huge and takes forever to open if I run it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the simple way isn't that efficient, but is it *really* too slow?

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: timeit words = list(open("sowpods.txt"))
10 loops, best of 3: 48.4 ms per loop

In [3]: words = list(open("sowpods.txt"))

In [4]: len(words)
Out[4]: 267751

In [5]: timeit random.choice([w for w in words if len(w.strip())==6])
10 loops, best of 3: 62.5 ms per loop

In [6]: random.choice([w for w in words if len(w.strip())==6])
Out[6]: 'NAPKIN\r\n'
```

The one liner version only takes less than a 10th of a second on this computer

```
In [7]: timeit random.choice([w for w in open("sowpods.txt") if len(w.strip())==6])
10 loops, best of 3: 91.2 ms per loop

In [8]: random.choice([w for w in open("sowpods.txt") if len(w.strip())==6])
Out[8]: 'REVEUR\r\n'
```

You can add a `.strip()` to that to get rid of the `'\r\n'` on the end